# Safari behavior - strange url - adware or what?

Tags: safari

During last few days, when I click on certain web pages and this strange URL comes for a second and then website gets opened.

```
http://203.94.248.63:3000/noti/?tm=1503169905239&fingerprint=c2VwLW5vLXJlZGlyZWN0&json=%7B%22url%22%3A%22%2F%22%2C%22referer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22host%22%3A%221blocker%2Ecom%22%2C%22categories%22%3A%5B0%5D%2C%22reputations%22%3A%5B1%5D%7D

http://203.94.248.63:3000/noti/?tm=1503167584314&fingerprint=c2VwLW5vLXJlZGlyZWN0&json=%7B%22url%22%3A%22%2F%22%2C%22referer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22host%22%3A%22me%2Ecom%22%2C%22categories%22%3A%5B0%5D%2C%22reputations%22%3A%5B1%5D%7D
```

Is my safari browser infected with something, any steps to avoid this irritating url behavior. Happened on chrome once too.

**Edit:** lengthy/detailed post on [security.stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/157828/my-isp-bsnl-india-is-injecting-ads-using-phozeca-which-spoils-websites-and-mak) , proposed solution is to modify hosts file.

Answer (score 2):

I read from this [post](https://broadbandforum.co/threads/link-not-opening-getting-stuck-at-mtnl-i-p.152873/), that it gets redirected to an Indian domain whenever you go to a website.

I'm not sure  if this would work, but just make sure that there are no VPNs running or block this domain in your router's configuration page: mtnl.phozeca.com

Answer (score 2):

The activity you are describing happens on the MTNL Delhi Network. MTNL Delhi Network is having some sort of a collaboration with an Advertisement Service Provider called Phozeca. They are interpreting all http:// URLs and injecting their own advertisement link.

I would suggest you block mtnl.phozeca.com:3000 in your router, and just manage with the attempted redirection that happens. You can also change your browser to always try https:// links, though that may not always work well for you.

You will not be getting much help from MTNL or BSNL - not only they are government owned, it is very difficult to reach people who can actually do something about it.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a domain registered in Delhi India. (I won't be visiting those URLs myself, just in case there is something kinky going on).

Problem is there may be perfectly legitimate reasons for those websites to be redirected first. Google does something similar for the purpose of monetizing their search service.

You need to provide more information, starting with the URLs in question.